# Do I need a listener and a callback with FusedLocationProviderClient?

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-location, fusedlocationproviderclient

I started using FusedLocationClient and I'm not sure why would I need both an OnSuccessListener and a LocationCallback. Shouldn't just one of these suffice?

```
private void initLocationCallback(Context context) {
    fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context);
    fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                    onLocationChanged(location);
                }
            });

    locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            if (locationResult != null) {
                for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                    if (location != null) {
                        onLocationChanged(location);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
    LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
    fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, context.getMainLooper());  
}
private void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // use location...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current#kotlin) when getting `lastKnownLocation()`,  `OnSuccessListener` should be enough also in rare cases Location might be null.

Personalty I am also using `OnSuccessListener()`

Answer (score 0):

If you are not interested in the user's exact location at this precise moment, then lastKnownLocation() and OnSuccessListener would suffice and you don't need a LocationCallback.

But if you want precise location and want regular updates in case the user is on the move, then you need to implement the LocationCallback to keep getting location updates. In this case, you would typically want the last known location as getting a location update might take some time.